# React Query - unable to access the data via 'getQueryData', always returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying out React Query for the first time and I wrote this:

```
export function Component(): JSX.Element {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  const { data } = useQuery<DataType>({
    queryKey: "myKey",
    queryFn: () => ....,
  })

  const sameData: DataType| undefined = queryClient.getQueryData("myKey")

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(data)}
      {console.log(sameData)}
      <p>Loaded, see console for values.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

The data object is created as expected, but I cannot seem to make sameData return anything other than undefined. I know this means that React Query isn't finding my key. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re creating a new QueryClient in each render, so you’ll get a new cache. Have a look at the example on the front page of the docs: https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview

You need a stable queryClient, and put it in a QueryClientProvider

Comment: Thanks! I understand now - super helpful!

Comment: Great answer - to add on top of this - make sure the query client is global outside any JSX component or at the root of it. For example on next.js I had the query client inside the Provider function component - while it works during development it breaks on static site generation. Creating the client on the root or simply outside the component solves any issue with it.

Comment: in nextjs, if you create the client outside of the component, it will be shared between requests and users on the server. that's why the recommendation with ssr to create it in useState: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/ssr#initial-setup

Answer (score 6):

like the above answer explained

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient()
```

will create a new instance on every render

the provided `useQueryClient()` hook returns the current instance

```js
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
```